# When pausing a video, how to get the current frame as a number?

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, frame, video.js

I am struggling with a problem. I am rendering a video with video.js and this is awesome. But I want to get the current frame number when I pause the video or if I click on a button, doesn't really matter. It is about getting the frame number of the exact moment from the video when it is paused or clicked.

I tried the normal method (time already played * fps) but this gives a number with a lot of decimals. So this is no option because it gives different numbers with the exact same frame.

Does anyone have a clue?

I am using Django frame work to te get the video from the database to html.

Comment: when you play a video in the browser, that's purely a html5 and javascript issue. django and opencv can't do anything about this. please adjust tags.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775499/get-current-frame-of-video-in-javascript-jquery